# What about windows 10 Insider Preview users for windows 10 Update?

Tags: windows-10-preview, windows-10-upgrade

I have upgrade my windows 8.1 to windows 10 Insider Preview. Microsoft announced free upgrade to program for windows 7,8, and 8.1 users. Wheather windows 10 Insider Preview users will get windows 10 update or not?

Comment: Users who are using Windows 10 Insider Preview will be able to upgrade to the final, it just won't be **FREE** only Windows 7 and Windows 8.1 users get Windows 10 for **FREE**

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Gabriel from Windows team at Microsoft today confirmed on Twitter that Windows Insiders who are trying earlier Windows 10 builds can upgrade to Windows 10 RTM for free when it is released.

[image]

This is not an surprising news given the fact that Microsoft has already announced free upgrade to Windows 10 for Windows 7, Windows 8 and Windows 8.1 users. Also, Microsoft is planning to continue Windows Insider program even after the release of Windows 10. So, Windows Insiders will anyway have access to latest Windows builds at any point of time than regular consumers.

Source: [Windows Insider Preview Users Can Upgrade To Windows 10 RTM For Free](http://microsoft-news.com/windows-insider-preview-users-can-upgrade-to-windows-10-rtm-for-free/)

Comment: But I don't have find any info about windows RTM update for preview users..?

Comment: @Kamal - Keep looking its there.  As evident by two identical answers.

Comment: Please comment on Downvotes folks :)